# How to get keys from hash in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In page.body I am getting this:

```
page.body = "{\"error\":\"Sorry, that is an invalid URL\"}
```

I want to fetch only "Sorry, that is an invalid URL".
When I am fetching like this page.body[:error], I am getting no implicit conversions.
When I am trying to see error is there or not like this:

```
  page.body.include? "error" 
  true
```

Can anyone help me to get error values.

Comment: `JSON.parse(page.body, symbolize_names: true)`

Comment: _"`page.body[:error]`"_ – you're treating `page.body` like a hash with symbolic keys, but it's merely a string. (hence the errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the json, to make a hash out of it and then you can check if the key exist like this:

```
require 'json'
JSON.parse(page.body).key? "error"
#=> true
```

To fetch the error value, it's almost the same approach:

```
JSON.parse("{\"error\":\"Sorry, that is an invalid URL\"}")["error"]
# => "Sorry, that is an invalid URL" 
# or
JSON.parse("{\"error\":\"Sorry, that is an invalid URL\"}").fetch("error")
# => "Sorry, that is an invalid URL"
```

Comment: `fetch` raises error if key is absent in the hash

Answer (score 0):

[`String#[]`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) doesn't accept symbol argument, that's why you have error

You need firstly convert string to hash, you can do it with [`JSON::[]`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/JSON.html#method-c-5B-5D)

```rb
page.body = "{\"error\":\"Sorry, that is an invalid URL\"}"
parsed_body = JSON[page.body, symbolize_names: true]
parsed_body[:error] # => "Sorry, that is an invalid URL"
```

Answer (score 0):

Return what do you want if there's no errors

```
require 'json'

def get_errors_from_json(page.body)
 parsed_json = JSON.parse(json_string) 
 error_message = parsed_json.key?("error") ? parsed_json["error"] : "No errors"
end
```